# replace a substring in oracle which does not have fixed length

Tags: sql, oracle

I have column value like:

```
1.   input -- "This is ssn12345 string" 
2.   input -- "This is ssn 123456 string"
3.   input -- "This is ssn#12345 string"
4.   input -- "This is ssn#12345 string ssn1234678"
5.   input -- "This is ssn#12345 string ssn-123456"
6.   input -- "This is ssn#12345 string ssn 5678 9765"
```

Here `ssn12345` can have dynamic length(mean length is not fixed).

output will be:

```
1.   output -- "This is ******** string"
2.   output -- "This is ********** string" 
3.   output -- "This is ********* string"
4.   output -- "This is ********* string *********"
5.   output -- "This is ********* string **********"
6.   output -- "This is ********* string *************"
```

I am trying to replace string which is starting from `ssn` and end with some integer values likes we are starting with `ssn1234` or `ssn124567`.

I am trying below query but it is replacing with single `*` value.

```sql
select regexp_replace('This is ssn12345 string', 'ssn[^0-9.]+', '*') from dual
```

> ```
> This is * string
> ```

I have to replace the value from `ssn` to next charcter with that number of `*` between these.

Can someone please tell me how this can be achieved in Oracle SQL? Let me know if more details are needed on the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just use "not White space" :

```
select regexp_replace(
'This is ssn12345 string',
 'ssn\S+',
Rpad( '*', length(regexp_substr('This is ssn12345 string','ssn\S+') ), '*') 
) 
from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
WITH data ( value, masked_value, end_pos ) AS (
  SELECT value,
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           value,
           'ssn([ #]?\d+)+',
           RPAD(
             '*',
             LENGTH(
               REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, 'ssn([ #]?\d+)+', 1, 1)
             ),
             '*'
           ),
           1,
           1
         ),
         REGEXP_INSTR(
           value,
           'ssn([ #]?\d+)+',
           1,
           1,
           1
         )
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT value,
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           masked_value,
           'ssn([ #]?\d+)+',
           RPAD(
             '*',
             LENGTH(
               REGEXP_SUBSTR(masked_value, 'ssn([ #]?\d+)+', end_pos, 1)
             ),
             '*'
           ),
           end_pos,
           1
         ),
         REGEXP_INSTR(
           masked_value,
           'ssn([ #]?\d+)+',
           end_pos,
           1,
           1
         )
  FROM   data
  WHERE  end_pos > 0
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY value SET value_order
SELECT value, masked_value
FROM   data
WHERE  end_pos = 0;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT 'This is ssn1 string' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'This is ssn12 string' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'This is ssn12345 string' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'This is ssn123456789 string' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'This is ssn#12345 string ssn 5678 9765' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE | MASKED_VALUE |
> | --- | --- |
> | This is ssn#12345 string ssn 5678 9765 | This is ********* string ************* |
> | This is ssn1 string | This is **** string |
> | This is ssn12 string | This is ***** string |
> | This is ssn12345 string | This is ******** string |
> | This is ssn123456789 string | This is ************ string |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ec15cc3191fdc8bb15b270e362b90649)*

Comment: Thank you so much