# masking data in a string having multiple data to be masked

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column value like:

Input:

1. `This is ssn12345 string dob 12-09-1998 string`
2. `This is ssn12345786 stringabc  string`

Output:

1. `This is ******** string ************** string`
2. `This is *********** stringabc  string`

whenever we found ssn or dob the value should be get masked as shown above example. string of dynamic length.

I am trying below query -

```sql
SELECT CASE 
       WHEN start_pos > 0 
       THEN SUBSTR( 'This is ssn12345 string dob 12-09-1998 string', 1, start_pos - 1) 
            || RPAD('*', end_pos - start_pos, '*') 
            || SUBSTR('This is ssn12345 string dob 12-09-1998 string', end_pos) 
       ELSE 'This is ssn12345 string dob 12-09-1998 string' 
       END AS masked_value 
FROM   ( 
  SELECT 'This is ssn12345 string dob 12-09-1998 string', 
         REGEXP_INSTR( 'This is ssn12345 string dob 12-09-1998 string', 'ssn[0-9. -]+' || 'dob[0-9. -]+', 1, 1, 0, NULL) AS start_pos, 
REGEXP_INSTR( 'This is ssn12345 string dob 12-09-1998 string', 'ssn[0-9. -]+' || 'dob[0-9. -]+', 1, 1, 1, NULL) AS end_pos 
  FROM   dual 
)
```

I am trying above query not getting as expected result as above
it is working only when we have -
input like - `This is ssn12345 dob 12-09-1998 string` then it masking
output as -  `This is ******** ************** string`

Comment: Are you selecting these values from a table? If so, could [Data Redaction](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/data-redaction-12cr1) help?

Answer (score 1):

From your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69570311/1509264), just change the regular expression you are matching:

```sql
WITH data ( value, masked_value, end_pos ) AS (
  SELECT value,
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           value,
           'ssn([ #]?\d+)+|dob ?(-?\d+)+',
           RPAD(
             '*',
             LENGTH(
               REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, 'ssn([ #]?\d+)+|dob ?(-?\d+)+', 1, 1)
             ),
             '*'
           ),
           1,
           1
         ),
         REGEXP_INSTR(
           value,
           'ssn([ #]?\d+)+|dob ?(-?\d+)+',
           1,
           1,
           1
         )
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT value,
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           masked_value,
           'ssn([ #]?\d+)+|dob ?(-?\d+)+',
           RPAD(
             '*',
             LENGTH(
               REGEXP_SUBSTR(masked_value, 'ssn([ #]?\d+)+|dob ?(-?\d+)+', end_pos, 1)
             ),
             '*'
           ),
           end_pos,
           1
         ),
         REGEXP_INSTR(
           masked_value,
           'ssn([ #]?\d+)+|dob ?(-?\d+)+',
           end_pos,
           1,
           1
         )
  FROM   data
  WHERE  end_pos > 0
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY value SET value_order
SELECT value, masked_value
FROM   data
WHERE  end_pos = 0;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT 'This is ssn1 string' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'This is ssn12 string' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'This is ssn12345 string' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'This is ssn123456789 string' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'This is ssn#12345 string ssn 5678 9765' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'This is ssn12345 string dob 12-09-1998 string' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'This is dob 12-09-1998 string' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE | MASKED_VALUE |
> | --- | --- |
> | This is dob 12-09-1998 string | This is ************** string |
> | This is ssn#12345 string ssn 5678 9765 | This is ********* string ************* |
> | This is ssn1 string | This is **** string |
> | This is ssn12 string | This is ***** string |
> | This is ssn12345 string | This is ******** string |
> | This is ssn12345 string dob 12-09-1998 string | This is ******** string ************** string |
> | This is ssn123456789 string | This is ************ string |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4324a37a57fc8450c3082d5d6f0cdda4)*

Answer (score 0):

This works but it replaces any matched string with a fixed number of asterixes.

```
WITH sample_data (c) AS
(
  SELECT 'This is ssn12. 34-5 string dob 12-09-1998 string' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '5 Strings: ssn12. 34-5,  dob 12-09-1998, nr 3: ssn18898, nr 4: dob 01-01-2000, nr 5:ssn1663' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'This is ssn12345786 stringabc  string' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT regexp_replace(c,'((ssn[0-9. -]+)|(dob [0-9. -]+))[0-9.-]','*******') FROM sample_data;


This is ******* string ******* string
5 Strings: *******,  *******, nr 3: *******, nr 4: *******, nr 5:*******
This is ******* stringabc  string
```

Comment: can you Please provide it for 5 Occurance if --

Comment: @SushilMishra This will work for any number of occurrences; however, it will not replace the text with dynamic length replacement strings (as the answer states, all the replacement strings will be the same length).

Comment: having issue with that dynamic query can you please make that query that can make it for 5 occurances it will be great

Comment: not sure what you mean by "5 occurences" - what does "having issue" mean ? It works fine for me for 5 strings in a single record.

Comment: it means 5 strings in a single record but with dynamic having issue in my tables can you please update as per the query for 2 as for 5 string

Comment: Updated my reply including a row with 5 strings. If that is not clear, please take time to give a _detailed_ explanation of what is wrong or add an update to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace a fixed number of occurrences of the pattern then you can use:

```sql
SELECT value,
       CASE
       WHEN start_pos2 > 0
       THEN SUBSTR( value, 1, start_pos1 - 1) 
            || RPAD('*', end_pos1 - start_pos1 - 1, '*') 
            || SUBSTR(value, end_pos1, start_pos2 - end_pos1) 
            || RPAD('*', end_pos2 - start_pos2, '*')
            || SUBSTR(value, end_pos2) 
       WHEN start_pos1 > 0 
       THEN SUBSTR( value, 1, start_pos1 - 1)
            || RPAD('*', end_pos1 - start_pos1, '*')
            || SUBSTR(value, end_pos1)
       ELSE value
       END AS masked_value 
FROM   ( 
  SELECT value, 
         REGEXP_INSTR( value, 'ssn([ #]*\d+)+|dob([. -]*\d+)+', 1, 1, 0, NULL) AS start_pos1, 
         REGEXP_INSTR( value, 'ssn([ #]*\d+)+|dob([. -]*\d+)+', 1, 1, 1, NULL) AS end_pos1,
         REGEXP_INSTR( value, 'ssn([ #]*\d+)+|dob([. -]*\d+)+', 1, 2, 0, NULL) AS start_pos2, 
         REGEXP_INSTR( value, 'ssn([ #]*\d+)+|dob([. -]*\d+)+', 1, 2, 1, NULL) AS end_pos2 
  FROM   table_name
);
```

*Note: this will only work for the first two occurrences in the string. If you need to match a dynamic number of occurrences then you will need to use a [recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69643990/1509264).*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT 'This is ssn1 string' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'This is ssn12 string' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'This is ssn12345 string' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'This is ssn123456789 string' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'This is ssn#12345 string ssn 5678 9765' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'This is ssn12345 string dob 12-09-1998 string' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'This is dob 12-09-1998 string' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE | MASKED_VALUE |
> | --- | --- |
> | This is ssn1 string | This is **** string |
> | This is ssn12 string | This is ***** string |
> | This is ssn12345 string | This is ******** string |
> | This is ssn123456789 string | This is ************ string |
> | This is ssn#12345 string ssn 5678 9765 | This is ******** string ************* |
> | This is ssn12345 string dob 12-09-1998 string | This is ******* string ************** string |
> | This is dob 12-09-1998 string | This is ************** string |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8e0a000feb37cc430496bb2b4523ec8c)*

Comment: @SushilMishra Just repeat the `REGEXP_INSTR` for 3, 4, and 5 and then add the extra `WHEN` clauses to the `CASE` expression following the same pattern.

Comment: @SushilMishra As I said, just repeat the REGEXP_INSTR for 3, 4, and 5 and then add the extra WHEN clauses to the CASE expression following the same pattern as for two. This is for 3 [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c413bc1276a8da5de02f9101806413f8) - **YOU** can add it for 4 and 5 if you want.

Comment: Just like another pattern was added for `dob`, you can then add another pattern for `DD` to the string. StackOverflow is not a code writing service; at some point **YOU** need to try to work out how to solve your problems rather than keeping coming back with incremental changes to the question. Alternatively, if you really cannot work it out then ask a new question.